# Is there some good way to globally hook CreateWindow or CreateProcess on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

Except hook each process directly, are there more elegant way? My target is to record the all windows or processes name  when they open .

Comment: Windows open & processes open are very different types of events and concepts. Here is one way to track window open: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428463/403671

Comment: You can use [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents) to monitor window creation and destruction. You can use the [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page) to monitor process creation and termination. You'll get better help if you provide an answer to the question: What's the specific *problem* you are trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable Just get the name of create window or process (pid or thread id also ok).Depending name,  I will close  window or process that I don't permit run .

Comment: That's not how security works. If you allow a program to launch, then all bets are off. You have to prevent the program from running altogether if you need any sort of reliability.