# How to get window open/creation date from window handle?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I have 2 MS Edge windows open in IE mode. I have to find out the one opened later. I have window handles for both. How can I do this? [GetWindowInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowinfo) function does not return the open date. Is this possible? ChatGPT proposed some code but it didn't work :D

Comment: You also can not get the weather condition from the time when you opened the window, just because the OS does not need this information to fulfill its job (handle the open windows).

Comment: The system doesn't record window creation times. The closest to what you're looking for would be asking the window's owning thread's creation time (see [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) and [`GetThreadTimes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadtimes)).

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, what is the broader picture? Chances are that there is a solution without the need for window creation date.

Comment: Here is the broader picture: We are developing a test automation framework. Users of this framework need to be able to operate on GUI objects on the browser. Sometimes an application under test opens more than one browser window. In this case, we want our framework to operate on the latest opened browser window. We are able to get an array of open browser windows and until now it was ordered by open date. But when Edge browser is opened in IE mode, the same array is not correctly ordered. This class in the answer can be used to query the open date times for each window in the array.

Comment: That seems like a valid use case. A possible solution could be implemented using UI automation. Register for the `WindowOpenedEvent` and store the current time in a dictionary that is indexed by the window handle. At the time when you get all browser windows, you could easily look up the opening date from the dictionary. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428463/7571258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple C# class to read creation date of a thread that opened a window specified by its handle. As Damien has warned below, thread creation and window open dates can differ.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class WindowCreationDateFinder
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

    // Import the GetThreadTimes function from the kernel32.dll
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetThreadTimes(IntPtr hThread, out long lpCreationTime,
        out long lpExitTime, out long lpKernelTime, out long lpUserTime);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetLastError();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr OpenThread(ThreadAccess dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [Flags]
    private enum ThreadAccess : int
    {
        QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0040
    }

    public static DateTime GetWindowCreationDate(uint windowHandle)
    {
        var threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(new IntPtr(windowHandle), out _);

        if (threadID == 0)
            ThrowWinApiError("GetWindowThreadProcessId");

        IntPtr threadHandle = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.QUERY_INFORMATION, false, threadID);

        if (threadHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            ThrowWinApiError("OpenThread");

        try
        {
            var b = GetThreadTimes(threadHandle, out long start, out long end, out long rawKernelTime, out long rawUserTime);

            if (!b)
                ThrowWinApiError("GetThreadTimes");

            return DateTime.FromFileTime(start);

        }
        finally
        {
            CloseHandle(threadHandle);
        }
    }

    private static void ThrowWinApiError(string funcCalled)
    {
        var m = $"{funcCalled} error: {GetLastError()}. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-";

        throw new Exception(m);
    }

}
```

Comment: Of course, the problem here is that it assumes the thread creation time is correlated with the window creation time. There's no requirement for such in the windows API, a single thread can own multiple windows, opened at vastly different times. So whilst it *may* appear to work against the exact current version of a third party application that you've tested against, realise that the other party is under no obligation to retain such behaviour.

Comment: Good point there Damien! Let's try this approach for a while and see if it works. For now it seems to work ok.

Comment: You cannot call `GetLastError()` from managed code. The value it returns is almost guaranteed to be indeterminate. You'll have to use the [`SetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror) attribute, and call the respective interop services API to discover the Win32 error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever For the general case you are right, but in the narrow use case of this Q&A the technique could be reliable. Browsers these days create each window or tab in a new process for security reasons, to isolate web pages from each other and from the main browser process. So its pretty safe to assume each window is associated with a different thread.